# Get column name where a condition is met after summing upto n columns

Tags: r, apply

I have the below data which contains the monthly sales by different salespeople

```
df_monthofsuccess
M1_Sales    M2_Sales    M3_Sales    M4_Sales    M5_Sales    M6_Sales
15000       16435       12144       55536       75260       15002
35853       41020       66689       0           51495       11725
2500        24600       0   0       3000        0           12445
80654       0           50625       275946      37320       43000
21578       40000       0   0       20000       0   0       20000
```

I want to find out the month in which they reach 1,00,000 and capture that month in a separate variable as shown below

```
M1_Sales    M2_Sales    M3_Sales    M4_Sales    M5_Sales    M6_Sales Month_Target
15000       16435       12144       55536       75260       15002       M5
35853       41020       66689       0           51495       11725       M3
2500        24600       0   0       3000        0           12445       FALSE
80654       0           50625       275946      37320       43000       M3
21578       40000       0   0       20000       0   0       20000       M6
```

I have tried with the below code:

```
df_success <- data.frame()
for (i in (1:nrow(df_monthofsuccess))){
  #i = 9
  x <- df_monthofsuccess[i,]
  ape_tot = 0
  month = 'FALSE'
  for (j in (2:ncol(x))){
    #j = 2
    ape_tot = ape_tot + x[,j]
    if (ape_tot > 100000) month = names(x)[j]
    x$monthofSuccess <- month
    next
  }
  df_success <- rbind(df_success,x)
}
```

However, this does not give the intented output and is slow.

Can anyone help me in getting the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `apply` to loop over the rows in `base R`, get the index of column where the cumulative sum of the the row is greater than 1e5, extract the `names` of the first element

```
df1$Month_Target <- apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) sub("_Sales", "", 
         names(which(cumsum(x) >1e5)[1])))
df1$Month_Target
#[1] "M5" "M3" NA   "M3" "M6"
```

NOTE: No packages used.  Only `base R`

---

Or using a vectorized approach with `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
m1 <- rowCumsums(as.matrix(df1)) 
substr(names(df1), 1, 2)[max.col(m1 > 1e5, "first") * NA^!(rowSums(m1 > 1e5))]
#[1] "M5" "M3" NA   "M3" "M6"
```

---

Or using `tidyverse` without doing any reshaping

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Month_Target = pmap(., ~ 
         names(which(cumsum(c(...)) >1e5)[1])) %>%
            str_remove("_Sales"))
#  M1_Sales M2_Sales M3_Sales M4_Sales M5_Sales M6_Sales Month_Target
#1    15000    16435    12144    55536    75260    15002           M5
#2    35853    41020    66689        0    51495    11725           M3
#3     2500    24600        0     3000        0    12445         <NA>
#4    80654        0    50625   275946    37320    43000           M3
#5    21578    40000        0    20000        0    20000           M6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(M1_Sales = c(15000L, 35853L, 2500L, 80654L, 21578L
), M2_Sales = c(16435L, 41020L, 24600L, 0L, 40000L), M3_Sales = c(12144L, 
66689L, 0L, 50625L, 0L), M4_Sales = c(55536L, 0L, 3000L, 275946L, 
20000L), M5_Sales = c(75260L, 51495L, 0L, 37320L, 0L), M6_Sales = c(15002L, 
11725L, 12445L, 43000L, 20000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Hello @akrun.. This code gives error, replacement has 0 rows, data has 5.

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` approach could be to `gather` the data to long format, `group_by` each `row` find the `month_name` when the cumulative values of `sales` reaches 100000 and `spread` it back to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  gather(month, sales, -row) %>%
  mutate(month_name = sub("_.*", "", month)) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(target = month_name[which(cumsum(sales) > 100000)[1]]) %>%
  select(-month_name) %>%
  spread(month, sales) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row)

#  target M1_Sales M2_Sales M3_Sales M4_Sales M5_Sales M6_Sales
#  <chr>     <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
#1 M5        15000    16435    12144    55536    75260    15002
#2 M3        35853    41020    66689        0    51495    11725
#3 NA         2500    24600        0     3000        0    12445
#4 M3        80654        0    50625   275946    37320    43000
#5 M6        21578    40000        0    20000        0    20000
```